SPFx http request fails within MS Teams when switching between edit & display mode
When viewing a SharePoint page within an MS Teams tab, http requests made after switching the page to edit mode are failing
Requests are made using the MSGraphClientFactory provided in the @microsoft/sp-http package.
This package automatically acquires a token from the SharePoint api endpoint AcquireOBOToken providing a clientId. The problem is that the clientId changes when you edit the SharePoint page. This results in the token aquisition failing.
Upon refreshing the iframe, the web part displays correctly again.
This behaviour is observed using MS Teams for web and SPFx 1.19.0.
Is it possible to allow a user to edit a SharePoint page from within MS Teams without causing the api requests to fail like this?

Steps to reproduce

Create a standard ReactJS SPFx webpart

Install @microsoft/sp-http library in the package

In the React component, make a request to the Graph API
import * as React from 'react';
import type { IHelloWorldProps } from './IHelloWorldProps';
import { MSGraphClientFactory } from '@microsoft/sp-http';

export default class HelloWorld extends React.Component<IHelloWorldProps, {email:string}> {
  constructor(props:IHelloWorldProps){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: ""
    };
  }
  public componentDidMount(): void {
    const { serviceScope } = this.props;
    serviceScope.whenFinished(async ()=>{
      const msGraphClientFactory = serviceScope.consume(MSGraphClientFactory.serviceKey);
      const msGraphClient = await msGraphClientFactory.getClient('3');
      const me = await msGraphClient.api(`/me`).get();
      this.setState({
        email: me.mail
      });
    });
  }
  public render(): React.ReactElement<IHelloWorldProps> {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.email && <p>Your email is {this.state.email}</p>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


Build, Bundle & Package the solution and upload to the app catalog

Add the web part to the homepage of a SharePoint site connected to a Teams channel

View the page in MS Teams and observe expected behvaiour - the email address is displayed

Edit the page and then save the page

Observe the email address is no longer displaying as expected



Please raise this issue on https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues.

I am checking to see how things are going there on this issue.

@Meghana-MSFT thanks, I have raised the issue here
